# Javascript FileReader and file synchronization

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, synchronization, filereader

So here's the thing: I have a file generate by a random application on my pc. The application can edit the file at random time, without any warning. I need to send the file to my server in a periodic manner, (like every 5 or 30 seconds). Before that I used a little cURL script, but since I often need to make this process from different workstations, I thinked to create a little page with a select input and a button that starts this function:

```
var syncFunc = function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText($("#file")[0].files[0]);
    reader.onload = function() { 
            var datas = reader.result; 

            $.ajax({
              url : 'callback',
              type : 'POST',
              data : {"data" : datas},
              success : function(data) {
              //do stuff
             },
            complete : function(data){
                syncTimeout = setTimeout(syncFunc, 5000);
            }
            });
    };
};
```

when I start the script it all goes well, until the file get changed by the application: **sometimes** (not always) FileReader throws a DOMException `NotReadableError` and `reader.result` contains `null`. The file can be read again without problem if I reselect it from the input, but if I don't do so, any subsequent tentative of reading it fails. And what bugs me more is that this happens in a actually random manner, where the same edit of the file selected sometimes does e sometimes does not generate the error.

Also, if I try to send the file using a FormData, the file is read and sent (as I can check using the Inspector and checking the HTTP request made), but the server throws the error "upload not completed")

Any idea?

Comment: How long do the file edits take by this other application? Possibly upset at being read and written at the same time. Does retrying onabort or onerror consistently fail or will it eventually work?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, since the error also happens if the edit is made 30 seconds before the reading tentative. Using onabort/onerror consistently fails